# Combining fields from two rows into a single row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In the data below, for each event I need to select the first row where the Date field is equal to or greater than the specified date and I need to select the row where the date is the largest date in the future beyond the specified date. However, I don't want to have two separate rows returned but rather one row per event where the date from the first record can be labeled as StartDate and the date from the second record is labeled EndDate. Here is the data:

Table EventDates

```
ID     EventID     Date
1        10     2013-12-01
2        10     2013-12-02
3        10     2013-12-03
4        10     2013-12-04
5        11     2013-12-03
6        11     2013-12-04
7        11     2013-12-31
```

So if I want to select events on or after 2013-12-02, the data selected would be:

```
ID     EventID     Date
2        10     2013-12-02
4        10     2013-12-04
5        11     2013-12-03
7        11     2013-12-31
```

but what I really want is:

```
ID     EventID     StartDate    EndDate
2        10     2013-12-02    2013-12-04
5        11     2013-12-03    2013-12-31
```

Note that the ID refers to the row with the lowest date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [Aggregate functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)?

```
SELECT      MIN(ID) AS ID               -- Smallest ID
            , EventID                   -- EventID
            , MIN(Date) AS StartDate    -- Earliest Date
            , MAX(Date) AS EndDate      -- Latest Date
FROM        table
WHERE       Date >= '2013-12-02'
GROUP BY    EventID                     -- From all records that share an EventID
```

**UPDATE**

You should be able to use a subquery if you want to return the `uniqueidentifier` ID:

```
SELECT      table.ID
            , aggregates.EventID
            , aggregates.StartDate
            , aggregates.EndDate
FROM        (
                SELECT      EventID                     -- EventID
                            , MIN(Date) AS StartDate    -- Earliest Date
                            , MAX(Date) AS EndDate      -- Latest Date
                FROM        table
                WHERE       Date >= '2013-12-02'
                GROUP BY    EventID                     -- From all records that share an EventID
            ) AS aggregates
            INNER JOIN table
                ON  table.EventID = aggregates.EventID
                AND table.Date = aggregates.StartDate
WHERE       Date >= '2013-12-02'
```

Comment: I actually simplified my data in the table above. The ID field is actually a uniqueidentifier. Your code won't work with that. I modified your answer to make it work with uniqueidentifiers but I had to give up returning the ID field.

Comment: @AndroidDev: Updated answer to allow usage of the `uniqueidentifier` ID.